# If type T2 is based on type T1, is there any sort of "inheritance" from T1 to T2?

Tags: types, go

If `type T2` is based on `type T1`, other than sharing the same data fields, is there any relationship between `T1` and `T2`?

```
package main
import "fmt"

type T1 struct { s string }
func (v *T1) F1() string { return v.s }

type T2 T1
func (v *T2) F2() string { return v.s }

func main() {
        var t1 = T1{ "xyz" }
        var t2 = T2{ "pdq" }
        s0 := t2.F1()                   // error - expected ok
        s1 := ((*T1)(&t2)).F1()         // ok - expected
        s2 := ((*T2)(&t1)).F2()         // ok - not expected
        fmt.Println( s0, s1, s2 )
}
```

My understanding here is lacking

1. was hoping that `T2` would inherit `T1`'s methods, but such is not the case.
2. was expecting `T2` could be coerced into `T1`, since it was derived from `T1`
3. was surprised that `T1` could be coerced into `T2`, but so it is.
4. it seems that the relationship between `T1` and `T2` is completely symmetrical - I cannot find anything that breaks the symmetry despite the fact one is actually derived from the other - or is this an illusion?

Comment: Wrong assumption: `T2` is *NOT* derived from `T1`. It only uses the same memory representation and is exactly the same as `type T2 struct { s string }`. The compiler keeps no link between `T1` and `T2`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go does not support object-oriented type inheritance.

[Is Go an object-oriented language?](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#Is_Go_an_object-oriented_language)

[Why is there no type inheritance?](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#inheritance)

A method is bound to a single specific type.

> A [method declaration](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Method_declarations) binds an
>   identifier to a method. The method is
>   said to be bound to the base type and
>   is visible only within selectors for
>   that type.

You can [convert](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Conversions) between types `T1` and `T2`.

> A value `x` can be [converted](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Conversions) to type
>   `T` [when] `x`'s type and `T` have
>   identical underlying types.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type T1 struct{ i int }

func (t T1) String() string { return "T1" }

type T2 T1

func (t T2) String() string { return "T2" }

func main() {
    t1 := T1{1}
    t2 := T2{2}
    fmt.Println(t1, t2)
    c1 := T1(t2)
    c2 := T2(t1)
    fmt.Println(c1, c2)
    t1 = T1(c2)
    t2 = T2(c1)
    fmt.Println(t1, t2)
}

Output:
T1 T2
T1 T2
T1 T2
```

Comment: so when you say `type T2 T1`, what's going on is that the structure of `T1` is copied as the structure of `T2`, and in that they have the same structure they can be recast to each other, and that otherwise `T2` has no relationship to `T1`

Comment: Yes. There are a lot of conversion rules. For this particular rule, the fact that `T1` and `T2` have the same underlying type means that they also have the same memory size, layout, and contents.

Answer (score 1):

I can explain why `T2` doesn't have methods of `T1`. Imagine that you need to sort some data of type `T` in two different ways. One way is default and so you implement `Len`, `Less` and `Swap` methods in `T`. You can call `sort.Sort(data)` and sort data in default way. But how to sort data differently?

You write `type SortDifferently T` and implement `Len`, `Less` and `Swap` methods for type `SortDifferently`. If `SortDifferently` had all methods of `T`, you couldn't do that because Go doesn't have methods overrides. But without inheritance you can now write `sort.Sort((SortDifferently)data)` to sort data in different way.

This is a Go way of doing things. It is not easy to get used to.

Comment: "Go doesn't have methods overrides" - I guess that explains it.

Comment: The thing is that Go *does* have method shadowing. If you use `type SortDifferently struct { T }`, it forwards all the methods from `T` to `SortDifferently`, and still allows you to shadow those names with methods written specifically on `SortDifferently`. You can still call the `T` versions, even from within the shadowing method. I don't really know why they disallow that on the `type SortDifferently T` case.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it'll help you but look at the "anonymous fields" described for instance in ["Go for C++ programmers"](http://golang.org/doc/go_for_cpp_programmers.html), under the "Interfaces" section -- it appears they provide something looking like child classes.

But in any case, reading through tutorials on Go, I developed an idea that Go's authors decidedly wanted programmers to steer away from building inheritance chains and use embedding/delegation instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
s2 := ((*T2)(&t1)).F2()         // ok - not expected
```

works because you cast it to type `T2`, and it thus allows `F2`. So it is expected to work. The `F2` function is then called on your `T2` object `t1` which returns `t1.s`.

```
s0 := t2.F1()                   // error - expected ok
```

For this one, I can not tell you for sure but only give you my plausible idea as well:

F1 is a method on type T1. As t2 is not of type T1 you can not call F1 on t2. So, as you noted, only data-fields are shared, not the methods on those types.

Also see [Go for C++ programmers](http://golang.org/doc/go_for_cpp_programmers.html), which states:

> Methods are defined on named types. If you convert the value to a different type, the new value will have the methods of the new type, not the old type.

Comment: `s2 := ((*T2)(&t1)).String()` doesn't work. But `s2 := T2(t1).String()` [does](https://go.dev/play/p/dQE6xdI7-8a).

Answer (score 0):

For another option, you can use embedding:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type T1 struct { s string }
func (v *T1) F1() string { return v.s }

type T2 struct { T1 }
func (v *T2) F2() string { return v.s }

func main() {
   a := new(T1).F1()
   // undefined (type *T1 has no field or method F2)
   // b := new(T1).F2()
   c := new(T2).F1()
   d := new(T2).F2()
   fmt.Print(a, c, d)
}
```

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types

Comment: The example code would be simpler without the use of pointers.