# In golang, implement method on custom type so cast in Println isn't necessary

Tags: go

I'm very new to golang. The code below is modified from:
https://jordanorelli.com/post/32665860244/how-to-use-interfaces-in-go

Why is the `time.Time()` required in the Println call in the last line?

Why does printing the `val["created_at"]` not produce the same string result? It produces a pointer instead.

You'll see I made a few attempts to create a Println function that works with the custom Timestamp type. Is it possible to define a function on the Timestamp custom type such that the Println functions at the end of the code output the string instead of a pointer?

I think this probably answers my question also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6485229/4005067

But is there a way to define some function of the Timestamp type so that the cast is not necessary?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

// start with a string representation of our JSON data
var input = `
{
    "created_at": "Thu May 31 00:00:01 +0000 2012"
}
`

type Timestamp time.Time

func (t *Timestamp) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    v, err := time.Parse(time.RubyDate, string(b[1:len(b)-1]))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *t = Timestamp(v)
    return nil
}

//func (t *Timestamp) Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error) {
//  return fmt.Println(time.Time(*t))
//}


//func (t Timestamp) String() string {
//  return string(t)
//}

func main() {
    // our target will be of type map[string]interface{}, which is a pretty generic type
    // that will give us a hashtable whose keys are strings, and whose values are of
    // type interface{}
    var val map[string]Timestamp

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &val); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(val)
    for k, v := range val {
        fmt.Println(k, reflect.TypeOf(v))
    }
    fmt.Println(val["created_at"])
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(val["created_at"]))
    fmt.Println(Timestamp(val["created_at"]))
    fmt.Println(time.Time(val["created_at"]))
}
```

Output on the go playground is:

```
map[created_at:{0 63474019201 0x5b0580}]
created_at main.Timestamp
{0 63474019201 0x5b0580}
main.Timestamp
{0 63474019201 0x5b0580}
2012-05-31 00:00:01 +0000 UTC
```

Comment: `string(t)` is a "type conversion" and doesn't do what you seem to expect. This is **not** an appropriate way to turn some value t into a string. Most of the time it doesn't compile at all and unless t is already of type string or type []byte it doesn't do what you you probably wish it would do. Such basics are covered in the Tour of Go which you might want to work through once more.

Comment: What you're after is covered [here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#printing) (informally) and [here](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing) — formally. Still, your question displays certain lack of basic knowledge of Go, so please consider following Volker's advice.

Comment: I'm not asking how to convert to a string. I'm asking which function needs to be defined for `Timestamp` so that it's done as part of Println. Turns out the function I need to define is `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a `String` method is one way to do it, just like you tried above.
With some small modification we can make it work.

```
func (t Timestamp) String() string {
  return time.Time(t).String()
}
```